# opencv: закраска градиентом по линиям через цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Нужно закрасить линию с градиентом от желтого к белому в цикле for. У меня в коде получается три линии разными цветами. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно закрасить?

```
import cv2
background_of_postcard = cv2.imread('python_snippets/external_data/photos/0bmFUg4BDepQDQu-.jpg')
i=0
for _ in range(50):
    background_of_postcard[20+i:30+i, :350] = (50+i, 255+i, 238)
    i += 150
cv2.namedWindow('test', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('test', background_of_postcard)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: А значения цветовых компонент у вас от скольки до скольки? Наверное от 0 до 255, а вы к 255 прибавляете сразу по 150

Comment: да,это я согласен, что до 255, тут просто привел пример, как сейчас написал. далее отлаживать надо. Сейчас загвоздка как раз с самим алгоритмом закраски, либо каждый пиксель красить, либо как то по линии, а после середины не красить.

Comment: Нарисуйте для начала в графическом редакторе тогда что вы хотите, я не очень понимаю. И напишите - от каких значений к каким вы хотите перейти. Так то выглядит просто - берёте длину `n` в течении которой цветовая компонента должна измениться от значения `a` до значения `b` и делаете цикл от `a` до `b` с шагом `(b-a)/n`. С тремя компонентами чуть сложнее, но суть рассуждений будет примерно та же.

Comment: получилось))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i=0
k=0
for _ in range(50):
    background_of_postcard[:,0+i:50+i] = (50+k, 255-k/8, 238)
    i += 20
    k += 5
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]